# How to perform a if statement inside an append method

Tags: jquery, append

I have a function that shows a pop-up with 8 thumbnails inside. In the pop-up there's a default picked thumbnail.

What I want to do is, in my loop, I want to check the thumbnail rel attribute (1 to 8). If it matches the default picked one, I want to add a selected state.

Code to generate the 8 thumbnails:

```
jQuery.each(videos[id], function(i, val) {
    $ul.append("<li><a rel='"+ (i+1) + "'><img src=" + val + "></a></li>");
});
```

I also have that variable that contains a number from 1 to 8 (this is the one that should have the selected class)

```
alreadySelectedThumb[id]
```

So basically, the logic (in word) is:

Loop trough the video array, if the rel attribute of the *a* tag is equal to *alreadySelectedThumb[id]* then add a class selected to that *a* tag.

Because its in an append function, I have no idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to reverse your append call making the new object the return,

```
var $image = $("<li><a rel='"+ (i+1) + "'><img src=" + val + "></a></li>").appendTo($ul);

if(whatever){
   $image.children("a").addClass("selected");
}
```

It keeps the code neater IMO.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for The [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)!

```
jQuery.each(videos[id], function(i, val) {
    var class = (i+1) === alreadySelectedThumb[id] ? 'myClass' : '';
    $ul.append("<li><a rel='"+ (i+1) + "' class='"+ class +"' ><img src=" + val + "></a></li>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript), which is just a part of Javascript (and a lot of other languages).

```
if (videos[id] == alreadySelectedThumb[id]) {
    something = "FOO";
} else {
    something = "BAR";
}
```

Would instead be written:

```
something = (videos[id] == alreadySelectedThumb[id]) ? "FOO" : "BAR";
```

Which could be inserted into a string assignment like this:

```
$ul.append("<li" + 
  ((videos[id] == alreadySelectedThumb[id]) ? ' class="selected" ' : '') +
  "><a rel='" + (i+1) + "'><img src=" + val + "></a></li>");
```

(sorry, that looks really messy to me, but I believe it's what you're looking for)

Comment: looks good, but that's not working! The selected class never get added!

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.each(videos[id], function(i, val) {
    var appendstr ="";
    if(/*select condition is true*/)
     appendstr  = "<li><a rel='"+ (i+1) + "'><img src=" + val + " class='selectclass'></a></li>"
    else
    appendstr  = "<li><a rel='"+ (i+1) + "'><img src=" + val + "></a></li>"
    $ul.append(appendstr);
});
```